# Couldn’t connect to Redis with colima : Server closed the connection

Tags: docker, redis, colima

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to use Redis with Colima as a Docker service on my Mac M1 Pro. I've attempted to connect to the Redis server, but error: "Error: Server closed the connection." I've experimented with different ports, but the problem persists.

[docker service is running in background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCIQ.png)
Here's a brief overview of my setup:

Mac M1 Pro
Docker service using Colima
colima version 0.5.6
runtime: docker
arch: aarch64

connecting redis cli with colima in macos